# Get the most precise time in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to get the most possible precis time using Ruby.  For example:

```
3.times.map do 
  Thread.new do
    # Expect 3 differnt results from each thread
    p Time.now.precis_time
  end
end.each(&:join)
```

However, even using the [strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.4/Time.html#method-i-strftime), I still can not achieve the goal. So is there any other way to get this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most precise timer available to Ruby is [`Process::clock_gettime`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Process.html#method-c-clock_gettime). To avoid losing precision to float rounding, use `:nanosecond` unit:

```
3.times { p Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_REALTIME, :nanosecond) }
# => 1491185078101717000
# => 1491185078101741000
# => 1491185078101747000
```

**EDIT:** This is the same time that is available by `Time.now`. On Linux, the two have nanosecond precision. However, there is another clock that has nanosecond precision even on OSX: `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`. This clock does not track time from epoch, but time from "some event", this event normally being your computer's boot time. To get the most precise time, one can take the difference between `CLOCK_REALTIME` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` and apply it later:

```
clock_diff = Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_REALTIME, :nanosecond) -
       Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC, :nanosecond)

3.times {
  nsec = Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC, :nanosecond) + clock_diff
  time = Time.at(nsec / 1_000_000_000, nsec % 1_000_000_000 / 1_000.0)
  p time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%N")
}
```

Comment: On OS X, both `Process::CLOCK_REALTIME` and `Time` have microsecond resolution. Only `Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC` has higher precision.

Comment: @Stefan: Thank you, I waffled between several answers. I will add this info.

Comment: @Stefan: No worries, good comment, I wouldn't have looked at machine differences twice. I still have no clue how any of it works on Windows, if at all... :P

Comment: @Amadan Another question is on JRuby, this method seems to be unimplemented. So, maybe after all, you have to use a case statement checking with the RUBY_PLATFORM

Comment: @HailongCao: I just executed my code on jruby-9.0.5.0 (on OS X and Linux), and it works. It indeed does not work on an older JRuby, and I don't know if it works on Windows at all.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, I think the most precise time is just `Time.now`. The `to_r` method "is intended to be used to get an accurate value representing the nanoseconds since the Epoch" (from the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-to_r)).

```
t = Time.now

p t.to_r  # =>(1491206113721862629/1000000000)
p [t.to_i, t.nsec] # =>[1491206113, 721862629]
```

Comment: And according to [`Process.clock_gettime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Process.html#clock_gettime-method): _"The origin in CLOCK_REALTIME is defined as the Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC). But some systems count leap seconds and others doesn’t. So the result can be interpreted differently across systems. **Time.now is recommended over CLOCK_REALTIME**."_ (emphasis added)

Answer (score 1):

On JRuby, you can use [`java.lang.System.nano_time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) :

```
java.lang.System.nano_time - java.lang.System.nano_time
# -15607
```

to get nanoseconds since a fixed but arbitrary origin. From the documentation :

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not
>   related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value
>   returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary origin
>   time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). The same
>   origin is used by all invocations of this method in an instance of a
>   Java virtual machine; other virtual machine instances are likely to
>   use a different origin.

If you want a precise Time with Java < 9, you could use [`currentTimeMillis`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) :

```
java.lang.System.current_time_millis
#=> 1491214503112
```

But then, you wouldn't get more information than from `Time.now` :

```
Time.now.to_f
#=> 1491214592.562
```

So `Time.now` might be your best bet : it will work on any Ruby version on any system. Note that nanoseconds precision [doesn't mean](https://www.ncsu.edu/labwrite/Experimental%20Design/accuracyprecision.htm) nanoseconds accuracy.

I dare say you could ignore any digit related to a shorter time than milliseconds. You could output the distance between NYC and Los-Angeles in micrometers, it doesn't mean it would be useful though.